# window open defined tab

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome

It looks easy to do such task but i'm not able to get it done.
How can i keep opening the same window using angularjs $window.open?
Looking at this fiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/fergnab/d8atdw0t/

```
var test = angular.module('test', []);

test.controller('testController', ['$compile', '$scope','$window', function($compile, $scope, $window) {
$scope.openWindow = function() {
    $window.open('http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/302/angularjs.aspx', 'C-Sharpcorner', 'width=500,height=400');
};}]);
```

When invoke openWindow function, i want to keep opening the same window instead of creating new one

**EDIT:**
I got this issue only with chrome

Comment: did you try     
     $window.location('http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/1/302/angularjs.aspx');

Comment: `$window.open(url, '_self')` should work

Comment: in the fiddle example, your code only opens 1 window for me, I am using firefox. I am not sure if that changes anything

Comment: @PankajParkar _self will update the current tab, but i want to update the other opened tab. Giving the example, i want to update C-Sharpcorner tab

Comment: @CostasVrahimis you are right, i get this issue with chrome